# Почему падает Logstash в докере с ошибкой: Expected one of [ \\t\\r\\n], \"#\", \"input\" ...?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Настраиваю ELK. Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы просто всё запустилось (Filebeat позже добавлю). Вроде всё сделал верно, но когда запускаю Logstash падает с ошибкой:

```
logstash-1       | Sending Logstash logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
logstash-1       | [2023-12-09T21:12:57,201][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Log4j configuration path used is: /usr/share/logstash/config/log4j2.properties
logstash-1       | [2023-12-09T21:12:57,231][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"8.10.2", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.4.2.0 (3.1.0) 2023-03-08 90d2913fda OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 17.0.8+7 on 17.0.8+7 +indy +jit [x86_64-linux]"}      
logstash-1       | [2023-12-09T21:12:57,238][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] JVM bootstrap flags: [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -Djava.a
wt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=true, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/uran
dom, -Dlog4j2.isThreadContextMapInheritable=true, -Dls.cgroup.cpuacct.path.override=/, -Dls.cgroup.cpu.path.override=/, -Xmx256m, -Xms256m, -Djr
uby.regexp.interruptible=true, -Djdk.io.File.enableADS=true, --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-exports=jdk.c
ompiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.
sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAM
ED, --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.nio.channels=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED]
logstash-1       | [2023-12-09T21:12:57,276][INFO ][logstash.settings        ] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.queue", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/queue"}
logstash-1       | [2023-12-09T21:12:57,282][INFO ][logstash.settings        ] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.dead_letter_queue", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/dead_letter_queue"}
logstash-1       | [2023-12-09T21:12:57,828][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] No persistent UUID file found. Generating new UUID {:uuid=>"d638b99d-5934-454f-bf51-953f2522bbe8", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/uuid"}
logstash-1       | [2023-12-09T21:12:59,026][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::P
ipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of [ \\t\\r\\n], \"#\", \"input\", \
"filter\", \"output\" at line 1, column 1 (byte 1)", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:32:in `compile_imp
erative'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:239:in `initialize'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:173:in `initi
alize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:48:in `initialize'", "org/jruby/RubyClass.java:931:in `new'", "/usr/sh
are/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:49:in `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:386:in `block in converge_state'"]}
logstash-1       | [2023-12-09T21:12:59,103][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600, :ssl_enabled=>false}
logstash-1       | [2023-12-09T21:12:59,124][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
logstash-1       | [2023-12-09T21:12:59,137][FATAL][org.logstash.Logstash    ] Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
logstash-1       | org.jruby.exceptions.SystemExit: (SystemExit) exit
logstash-1       |   at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:795) ~[jruby.jar:?]
logstash-1       |   at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:758) ~[jruby.jar:?]
logstash-1       |   at usr.share.logstash.lib.bootstrap.environment.<main>(/usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:90) ~[?:?]
logstash-1 exited with code 1
```

Но не понимаю почему. Сделал `logstash.conf`:

```
input {
    beats {
        port => 5044
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
    }
}
```

И `logstash.yml`:

```
pipeline.batch.size: 125
pipeline.batch.delay: 50
xpack.monitoring.enabled: false
```

`docker-compose.yml` выглядит так:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - main

  logstash:
    image: logstash:8.10.2
    labels:
      co.elastic.logs/enabled: "false"
    ports:
      - "5044:5044"
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    volumes:
      - ./Configs/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml:ro,Z
      - ./Configs/logstash.conf:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf:ro,Z
    depends_on:
      - app
    networks:
      - main

  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:8.10.2
    labels:
      co.elastic.logs/enabled: "false"
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 32767
        hard: 32767
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    depends_on:
      - logstash
    networks:
      - main

  kibana:
    image: kibana:8.10.2
    labels:
      co.elastic.logs/enabled: "false"
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    networks:
      - main

volumes:
  elasticsearch-data:

networks:
  main:
```

В ошибке говорится про неправильные символы в конфигах логстеша. Посмотрел в докере - конфиги выглядят так:

[image]

Есть какая-то красная точка. Может её можно как-то не добавлять? Может ли быть в этом проблема?

Comment: видимо проблема в пробеле в начале первой строки, yaml вроде к этому строг, так как файл монтируется, поменяйте его на сервер `./Configs/logstash.yml`

Comment: @ipatev_nn спасибо за ответ, но не совсем понял, что нужно сделать. Поменять на контейнере `/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml`? Не получается: если контейнер выключен - вылазит ошибка, которая говорит, что контейнер выключен; если контейнер включен, то не успеваю сделать изменения, потому что сервис с логстешом ломается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю как это произошло и почему, но когда я создавал файлы конфигов логстеша, я делал это в райдере. Он создал файлы с кодировкой `UTF-8 with BOM` и добавил невидимый символ. Скачал Notepad++ и поменял кодировку на `UTF-8` и всё заработало.